# Android Outsourcing Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, navigation, drawer

how can I create a class that instantiates my navigation drawer correctly?
I want to outsource it because it is a lot of code and its always the same.
I already tried to create such a class. The problem is,
there are these two methods:

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

that are overriden in the activity itself. Moreover the title doesnt change if the drawer is opened/closed and at last the arrow that is used as the button to open is not animated!

Thx for help!

Comment: create an interface to give a call back to the activity and there u can change the titles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First android studio provides a template for creating Drawer Activity. If you are going to create your project for the first time you can use:

[image]

or if you have created your project and you want to create a Drawer Activity you can find it like this:

[image]

Now if you do not like above approaches you can create an abstract activity class name it for example `DrawerActivity` and do all initialization in it. Then in every project you can add it and extends it. That is one time work. But you must design it carefully so it must be general enough and also meet your common requirements. For example it can have a `protected DrawerLayout` field so when you extends it you initialize that field after `setContentView` of subclass `activity` and all the stuff like  `onPostCreate` and `onConfigurationChanged` are done in the `DrawerActivity`(superclass).